# Botão mostrar/esconder aparece só para o post inicial

Tags: php, html, wordpress

No primeiro post, aparece normalmente, mas quando clico nos outros, aparece somente o conteúdo do primeiro post.

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="caixapost">
<div class="title" style="height: 27px;">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<button title="Clique para mostrar/ocultar" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">+</button>
</div>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none"><?php the_content(); ?></div> 


</div>
 
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você monta as div's dentro de um while certo? então dessa forma várias div's estão recebendo o id spoiler. O id deve ser único, por isso só está reconhecendo o primeiro.

Comment: Como eu posso fazer usando o while?

Comment: Quais informações do sql você tem dentro do while?